# Bash script while loop stops after reading the first line of text file

Tags: bash, while-loop, readfile

#### Goal:

I have a bash script to:

> - read lines in a file;
> - set the value of each line as parameter; and
> - use the parameter as part of path.

#### Script:

```
fileName='s3Path.txt'
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ "$line" ]]; do

        printerType=$line
        gcPath=s3://gc-reporting-pud-production/structured_printer_log_files/
        gcFullPath=$gcPath$printerType
        echo $gcFullPath
done < $fileName
```

#### Problem:

The loop stops after the first line in the file. How can I solve it?

Comment: the script seems to be fine - it seems that the problem is with the content of `s3Path.txt` - can you please share the `s3Path.txt` content?

Comment: `please share the s3Path.txt content` especially 2nd&3rd line

Comment: `awk '{print "s3://gc-reporting-pud-production/structured_printer_log_files/"$0}' s3Path.txt`.

Comment: Star F170
Star F270
Star F370

Comment: @sarit Please *edit* your question to include the output of `od -c f | head` so that we can check that the file does not contain strange control characters. Also, please show us the output of `echo "$SHELL"` when added at the start of your script, or even better `pstree -s $$`, so that we can confirm that you are using the correct shell. The version of `bash` could also be relevant; what is the output of `bash --version` (only paste the version number)? Remember: You can **edit your question**, no one wants to read all these informations in comments.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your problem. For me the loop iterates over all lines in some test file.

You could try the following script which basically does the same thing as your loop. I would also expect this alternative script to be more efficient than your loop.

```
mapfile -t lines < s3Path.txt
printf 's3://gc-reporting-pud-production/structured_printer_log_files/%s\n' "${lines[@]}"
```

Comment: thanks but this solution wont work for me since i have to concatenate the variable from the file with some more commands . it must be in some loop

Comment: @sarit This command concatenates each lines with other strings as in your script from the question. If your actual script is different and calls a command for each line, then of course this might not work. However, if your actual script is different you might have hidden the actual problem from us. Please make sure that the script you show us has the exact same problem you are having. Did you copy and run your script from the question? Are you experiencing the problem you described?

Answer (score -1):

When writing a `bash script` the script should start with:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

To explicit specify to use bash (it might work without it if you are using `bash` as your shell).

I've execute your script and it worked fine with my input data.

The source of the problem might be:

- Lack of `#!/bin/bash` in the first line of the script
- Issue with your input file

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: this line exists in my script. i just posted the relevant part of the script